# How to know the address range of kernel stack in user process and kernel thread?

Tags: stack, kernel, freebsd

I'd like to know the address range of *kernel stack*. For user-space process, we can use `/proc/pid/maps` to see the stack address range by keyword `[stack]`, but do not know which one is kernel stack. For kernel thread, usually `/proc/pid/maps` is empty.

So how can I know the kernel stack address range, in user-space process and kernel thread for FreeBSD?

---

### Edit:

It seems that kernel allocates two pages (IA-32) for each kernel thread, how could we find the address of these two pages under x86_64? (Maybe x86_64 is a little different)

Comment: FreeBSD or Linux? Pick one. They work rather differently.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The kernel's stack is not (as far as I know) mapped into the address space of user processes at all.

Comment: So all the user-space's kernel stacks are in the same address space (the kernel's)? And how can we know their ranges?

Comment: AFAIK the kernel's stack is not mapped into a user-space process at al. If you think about it, that would be an obvious security hole. I'm thus not sure what you are asking as such a range does not exist.

Comment: I mean if not mapped into user-space process, so we can find them in the `kernel's address space` or `kernel threads' address spaces`. How could we find them (the ranges)?

Comment: Find them from where? If you mean from userspace, there is *no* logical address range in userspace that corresponds to the kernel's stack space. There is nothing to find.

Comment: Find them from kernel. Could we write a kernel module to read the beginning and ending addresses of each kernel stack?

Comment: In the kernel simply take the address of a variable on the stack. Kernel stacks are of fixed size so you can elucidate the start and the end by alignment operations. There may be a cleaner way.

Answer (score 0):

Under Linux kernel 3.10, a kernel thread can get its stack starting point by current->stack, where current is a pointer of struct task_struct.